# Linking Github REST API actor id to all username's/emails

Tags: github, github-api

How can I get the actor id associated with a commit in github? If I look at my [public events profile](https://api.github.com/users/liaochris/events/public)
on the Github REST API, I can see my actor id is 33707455.

However, if I look at the logs for my repositories, I can only see my github username (or my name) and the email address associated with the commits, not my actor id. For example, the command

`git shortlog -s -n -e` returns

```
24  liaochris <christopher.liao.2002@gmail.com>
13  Chris Liao <chrisliao@cs.uchicago.edu>
 8  liaochris <chrisliao@cs.uchicago.edu>
```

Is there a way to obtain the actor id associated with each commit from a local clone of a repository? I know that the Github REST API will link a user's primary email to their actor id, but as is evident in the example above, the primary email is not always used for all of the commits, and whether a username or a name is used is not consistent either.